# How to solve this numerically?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

May I ask what is the best way to evaluate

```
NSolve[{a^10 E^-a - b^10 E^-b == 
   0, (362880 + 
       a (362880 + 
          a (181440 + 
             a (60480 + 
                a (15120 + 
                   a (3024 + 
                    a (504 + 
                    a (72 + a (9 + a))))))))) E^-a + (-362880 - 
       b (362880 + 
          b (181440 + 
             b (60480 + 
                b (15120 + 
                   b (3024 + 
                    b (504 + b (72 + b (9 + b))))))))) E^-b + 0.99 == 
   0}, {a, b}]
```

I tried several methods but my machine refuse to produce anything. Is the computational complexity really this much?

Comment: By the way, though you've probably already done this, those numbers seem to match sequence [A008279](https://oeis.org/search?q=9%2C72%2C504%2C3024&sort=&language=english&go=Search), a.k.a. permutation coefficients, a.k.a. falling factorials triangle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reformulate this as a objective function minimisation problem, where you minimise the sum of the squares of the left hand sides of your equations. Here is how to do this with `NMinimize`, trying all of the optimisation methods that are mentioned in the documentation:

```
{#, NMinimize[(a^10 E^-a - 
   b^10 E^-b)^2 + ((362880. + 
      a (362880. + 
         a (181440. + 
            a (60480. + 
               a (15120. + 
                a (3024. + 
                a (504. + 
                a (72. + a (9. + a))))))))) E^-a + (-362880. - 
      b (362880. + 
         b (181440. + 
            b (60480. + 
               b (15120. + 
                b (3024. + 
                b (504. + b (72. + b (9. + b))))))))) E^-b + 
   0.99)^2, {a, b}, Method -> #]} & /@
{"NelderMead", "DifferentialEvolution", "SimulatedAnnealing", "RandomSearch"}
```

which produces the output

```
{{"NelderMead", {0.965138, {a -> 1.96905, b -> 1.96881}}},
 {"DifferentialEvolution", {3.38813*10^-21, {a -> 1.69024, b -> -1.25858}}},
 {"SimulatedAnnealing", {1.11485*10^-20, {a -> 1.69024, b -> -1.25858}}},
 {"RandomSearch", {0.968532, {a -> 0.900447, b -> 0.774213}}}}
```

Both `"DifferentialEvolution"` and `"SimulatedAnnealing"` have found an accurate solution.

Comment: Ah, so that's how it's done!

Comment: I had another think about my solution when I read Andrew Cheong’s answer below. Define f1[a_,b_]:=<LHS #1>; f2[a_,b_]:=<LHS #2>, where "LHS" means "left hand side", then evaluate `ContourPlot[{f1[a, b] == 0, f2[a, b] == 0}, {a, -50, 50}, {b, -50, 50}, ContourStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotPoints -> 100]`, where any solution corresponds to an intersection between the red and blue contours. Ignoring near-solutions where contours run very close to each other, there are 2 solutions: (1) close to (10,10) as noted by Andrew Cheong below, and (2) at `{1.69024…, -1.25858…}` as found in my answer above.